# What is the purpose of the -u argument for mysql?

Tags: mysql

On page 240 of the 4th ed. I see this listed as a command...

```
mysql -u root
```

I enter this and it fails on my Mac, says access denied for user `root@localhost`.  I cannot find ANYWHERE what this means. What does the flag `-u` represent? Where can I find a list of all flags for the mysql command. Have i had too much coffee? Why is this so hard to find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find out what that flag means, you can type `mysql --help` or `man mysql` at your prompt. Those commands will tell you the options and usage of virtually every command line program on your system.

You can also read the [MySQL Reference Manual :: mysql options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html) webpage.

Your question is titled "what is the purpose of the -u argument for mysql" -- if you made the related Google search "mysql arguments" you would have found the answer in the first result there as well.

Comment: yeah...i had too much coffee.

Answer (score 4):

The `-u` flag specifies the username. Access is denied because you didn't specify the `-p` flag for the password.

Type `mysql --help` for more information.

Comment: Exactly, I just figured it out. The problem is that the authors for the text assumed I would understand this already. It's been years since I hit command line mysql stuff even the most basic. It would have been nice if the authors of the text informed those of us with mysql already in use on our machines and password protected that we need to do "mysql -u root -p" instead of "mysql -u root" as indicated in the text.

Answer (score 2):

> "access denied for user root@localhost"

means that you need a password most likely.
The "-u" flag tells the mysql client to use the user specified after the -u option.

Answer (score 1):

The "-u root" means "login as database user 'root'"

For more information on mysql command-line arguments, type:

"mysql --help"

Answer (score 1):

As to not add the same answer as everyone else has already said, you will get an access denied message if you do not enter a password. It will tell you in the error message if this is the case:

```
$ mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

In order to get around this, you must provide the MySQL root password in this case (or the corresponding password for other users)

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
```